# How can i copy Files from .jar into local FS

Tags: java, javafx

i want to safe my Files from .jar to local FS during runtime. If i start this with netbeans, i can safe the Files but if i start my dist .jar i founds no Files...

I tried it with MyClass.clas.getResource("src/scripteInklErklaerung/Mustertest_24STUNDENBELASTUNG.tts").toExternalForm ...

Can anyone tell my the right way?

I have a .fxml-File with 5 CheckBoxes in, and if you select multiple of them you can click on safe-Button to safe the File to the local FS:

```
@FXML Button btn_infoAusf;
@FXML CheckBox cb_ausfuehrlich;
@FXML CheckBox cb_eingang;
@FXML CheckBox cb_ausgang;
@FXML CheckBox cb_schnell;
@FXML CheckBox cb_24;
@FXML Button btn_saveToStick;

File pathAusf = new File("/scripteInklErklaerung/Mustertest_AUSFUEHRLICH.tts");
File pathEing = new File("src/scripteInklErklaerung/Mustertest_EINGANG.tts");
File pathAusg = new File("src/scripteInklErklaerung/Mustertest_AUSGANG.tts");
File pathSchnell = new File("src/scripteInklErklaerung/Mustertest_SCHNELL.tts");
File path24 = new File("src/scripteInklErklaerung/Mustertest_24STUNDENBELASTUNG.tts");


ObservableList<CheckBox> cb = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<File> scripte = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

public void getPrimaryStage(Stage stage){
    this.primaryStage=stage;
}

public void createPath(){
    if(cb_ausfuehrlich.isSelected()){
        scripte.add(pathAusf);
    }
    if(cb_eingang.isSelected()){
        scripte.add(pathEing);
    }
    if(cb_ausgang.isSelected()){
         scripte.add(pathAusg);
    }
    if(cb_schnell.isSelected()){
        scripte.add(pathSchnell);
    }
    if(cb_24.isSelected()){
        scripte.add(path24);
    }
}

public void saveTestsToStick(ActionEvent event){
    try{
    createPath();
    System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    DirectoryChooser fileSaveDialog = new DirectoryChooser();
    fileSaveDialog.setTitle("Vorgefertigte Dauertest speichern Pfad: toolhouseUSB-Stick/testlx/DAUERTEST");
    Stage stage = (Stage) btn_saveToStick.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
    File saveFile = fileSaveDialog.showDialog(primaryStage);
    for(int i=0;i<scripte.size();i++){
    File realPath = new File(saveFile+"\\"+scripte.get(i).getName());
    Files.copy(scripte.get(i).toPath(), realPath.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING);
    System.out.println(scripte.get(i));
    }
    }catch(NullPointerException|IOException ex){System.out.println(ex);}
}

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    btn_saveToStick.setOnAction(this::saveTestsToStick);
    cb.add(cb_ausfuehrlich);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need an absolute path if you refer to a file in your jar, so I would try it with:

```
MyClass.clas.getResource("/src/scripteInklErklaerung/Mustertest_24STUNDENBELASTUNG.tts")
```

note the `/` at the beginning of the path.

If this doesn't help, it might be that `Files` cannot work with paths from inside Jars. In this case, get an `InputStream` from your Resource, open a `FileOutputStream` for your destination file, and then read content from the InputStream and write it to your OutputStream to manually copy the file out of your Jar:

```
public static void copyStream(final InputStream fromStream, final OutputStream toStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fromStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        toStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```